# Mxchip IoT DevKit - Not showing up as USB device, programming LED flashing

Tags: iot-devkit

I am following the Getting Started Guide (https://microsoft.github.io/azure-iot-developer-kit/docs/get-started/) for the MXCHIP IoT DevKit.  I got it connected to WIFI but the device does not show up as a USB device in Windows Explorer which is needed to update the firmware.  Also the programming LED is continually blinking.

Any suggestions to get this issues resolved as it needs to be active as a USB device to continue working with the board.

Comment: Have you installed the USB driver from the STM website as instructed here?

https://microsoft.github.io/azure-iot-developer-kit/docs/get-started/#prepare-the-development-environment

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT I did install the ST-Link drivers per the instructions.  That seems to install the drivers okay but the device does not show up in my device manager or as a USB disk.  I have tried this on two Win10 computers and two IoT DevKit devices.

Comment: Can you try a different cable to rule this out? Fwiw, it works here.

Comment: Did you find a way to get your device to connect? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: usb cable was the problem. It worked after connecting a different cable

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the USB cable is connected properly. I had the same issue but finally, I found that that I hadn't pushed the cable firmly enough.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with a drive already being mapped, so it took me a while to figure out it was mislabeled AND appeared to be unavailable (red x).

[image]

My advice is to look at other drive options and see if they contain file `DETAILS.TXT`

Answer (score -1):

usb cable was the problem. It worked after connecting a different cable